# ffmpeg is consuming 100% CPU

Tags: java, spring-boot, ffmpeg

I am trying to run below ffmpeg command from Java application.

```
ffmpeg -y -v error -i ~/Downloads/call.wav -af "volume=enable='between(t,5,7)':volume=0" ~/Downloads/call_0.wav
```

I am using below dependency as ffmpeg wrapper

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.bramp.ffmpeg</groupId>
  <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am running this operation in loop for 1000s of files. I can see the CPU utilization immediately going to 100% and stays there untill the job gets finished.
I am using c5a.large instance.
Is there any flag in ffmpeg that can optimize the CPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cgroup` wrapper to acheive this.

https://github.com/haosdent/jcgroup

Run your ffmpeg code in a thread, assign this thread to a created `cgroup` with required cpu share

Or alternatively run `ffmpeg` with a nice command like `nice -n 19 ffmpeg -y ...`